# Why does awaiting a setInterval promise inside of a while loop cause the amount of calls to stack up?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I was just trying to make a simple async function that runs on a schedule. I was just starting off with a counter. But this loop is behaving differently from how I imagined.

```
async function runCheckChats(){
  while(true){
    count++
    console.log(`this loop is running`);
    await new Promise(res => {
      setInterval(() => {
        count++
        res(3);
      }, 3000)
    })

    console.log(`count = ${count}`)

  }
}

runCheckChats();
```

The first time the loop runs, count is increased by one. The second time, it's increased by two, and so on. Why is this happening? When we await a promise, wouldn't we be exiting runCheckChats in the event loop? Why does it seem like the while keeps going instead of waiting? I would expect it to count every 3 seconds.

Comment: Because you are confusing synchronous programming with asynchrnonous programming.

Comment: You probably meant to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`?

Answer (score 4):

Intervals fire repeatedly, and you're creating more and more intervals.

You start off by creating an interval, and after 3 seconds it fires, increments `count`, and resolves the promise. Since the promise has resolved, you repeat your loop and create an additional interval. After 3 more seconds, **both** of the intervals go off. They each increment count, and each resolve their corresponding promise (one of them is already resolved, so that does nothing). And then repeat again, now with 3 intervals.

If you want to keep the code roughly the same way it is now, use a timeout instead of an interval. Timeouts only go off once, so when one ends you can safely create another without they piling up.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  count++
  res(3);
}, 3000)
```

Alternatively you could rework the code to use just a single interval, but in that case promises won't be a good fit, since promises can only resolve once.

```
function runCheckChats() {
  setInterval(() => {
    count++;
    console.log(`count = ${count}`)
  }, 3000);
}
```